# Isolating devices in same subnet

Tags: networking, vlan

Is there anyway to isolate devices that belong to the same subnet ?
In other words, isolate some devices in the subnet from the broadcast domains.
I was thinking of using vlans but I guess it is not functional.
I'm using SF200 cisco switch

Answer (score 0):

my english is not very well

but i think vlan is a good way to solve you problem.

you can bulit two vlan in switch. and put the devices in different vlans.
communication with different vlans you can use some devices worked in 3 layer.

Comment: In this case I would have to put the devices in different subnets and add routing. This is not the case, I want layer 2 isolation such that devices stay in same subnet.

Comment: I kown what you mean.But i don't kown why are you doing like this.As you kown,different Vlan is used to  isolate the different broadcast domains.But you want isolate the different broadcast domains in  the same vlan.it's paradoxical. But if you are want the different host can't connect each other,you can use the host firewall.you can bulit the access list contorl and permit or deny some IP.

Comment: I have 3 access points connected to the switches and serving wireless devices. The issue is that the access point are loaded due to the high traffic on the broadcast domain. I want to isolate these access points but keep them in the same subnet so that users can access the network without the need for routing.